# Accessing a class from xml android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a class where I am creating a customized GridView viz. MyGridView.Java . I have this class in a seperate folder in my project. Iam trying to access this class from my xml file like follows:-

main.xml

```
 <MyGridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        >
        </MyGridView>
```

I have also tried:-

```
<com.mypackage.myproject.seperatefolder.MyGridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />
```

and

```
<view class="com.mypackage.myproject.seperatefolder.MyGridView"
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />
```

But I always get an error:-

```
04-21 10:54:18.793: E/AndroidRuntime(2378): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.MyGridView
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Your class should implement 3 constructors public MyGridView(Context context), public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs), public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle). And <com.mypackage.myproject.seperatefolder.MyGridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        /> will work

Comment: @Kolchuga I already have them

Comment: Make sure they are public and It is the fully qualified name of the MyGridView in xml. Clear project and rebuild and post MyGridView code here.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? For example, if i create a sub source folder (let's call it views) in the package com.example it would be com.example.views. If i create class that extends View, let's call it MyCustomView.java, then the xnl would be <com.example.views.MyCustomView ... />. As Kolchuga mentioned you also need the three constructors from the super class (View).